# Ennunciate Documentation for tweaking the output

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, enunciate

I've found that ennuciate is good at documenting our JAXB REST webservice but there appears to be minimal documentation on how to tweak the output generated.

Is there a definitive list of annotations that we can use to describe the parameters for the webservices and the list of acceptable values.

It's not clear how the documentation generation code splits the classes up into **Data Types** and **Data Elements**

Thanks

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Enunciate honors the [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/) and [JAX-RS](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) annotations to customize parameters and models. Use those annotations to customize output. To understand "data types" vs. "data elements" refer to [this guide](http://www.xfront.com/ElementVersusType.html) (hint: it's the difference between an XML type and XML element).